# What triggers LBN_SELCANCEL?

Tags: mfc, clistbox

I'm trying to understand the listbox notification LBN_SELCANCEL.  MSDN says "Notifies the application that the user has canceled the selection in a list box."  OK, but how exactly does a user "cancel the notification"?  I've got LBS_NOTIFY set, and I've tried selecting another item, clicking outside the listbox, clicking another window, and none of these trigger LBN_SELCANCEL.

Anyone know what specifically triggers this notification?

Comment: Please post your message map code that is attempting to handle the notification, and the RC declaration of the listbox (if it's in a resource) or code that creates the listbox.

Answer (score 1):

I believe LBN_SELCANCEL only applies to ComboBox controls because they also use lists.
It should be called when you open the drop down hover over an element then press ESC.